# Search view in instant apps. Intent does not fire in Samsung devices/emulator

Tags: android, google-play, searchview, android-instant-apps

I am building out an instant app for my existing app in the app store. The full app has a searchview that shows a list of results. When the user taps on one of the results, onNewIntent gets fired which in turn helps me do things in the app.

When porting the code the onNewIntent gets fired in the instant app as expected in a Google Pixel 3 device but the same event doesn't fire on Samsung devices or the emulator.

I have tried most of the stuff mentioned in Stackoverflow. In my AndroidManifest I have the

```
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="Test"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".Activity" />
        </activity>
```

So I would expect the onNewIntent to fire across all devices and OS levels in the instant app but it only seems to fire on the Google Pixel. Ideas?

Comment: does the `onNewIntent` get fired when this is an installed-app? Samsung or emulator?

Comment: yes. Looks like instant apps for some reason blocks the search_intent in some devices. In the end we wont be able to rely on this intent handling for a search view.

Comment: Which Android operating system versions were you using for the Samsung phone and the emulator during their failures?  Was there some kind of a failure message from your logs?